# Casting Down from Base class

Tags: c#

I know casting is not inherently bad practice, but is it bad in this situation?

I have the following class hierarchy, and the cast at the end.

```
    public class A<T>
    {
        public A(string name, T value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
        public T Value { get; }
    }

    public class B : A<double>
    {
        public B(string name, double value, string expression)
            : base(name, value)
        {
            Expression = expression;
        }

        public string Expression { get; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public C(A<double> a)
        {
            _a = a;
        }

        public string Name { get { return _a.Name; } }
        public double Value { get { return _a.Value; } }
        protected A<double> _a;
    }

    public class D : C
    {
        public D(B b) : base(b)
        {
        }

        public string Expression { get { return ((B)_a).Expression; } }
    }
```

The line in question:
**public string Expression { get { return ((B)_a).Expression; } }**

Comment: Your constructor of D can take an instance of B and pass that to base constructor because B is a subclass of A<double> so id say s

Comment: Also you haven't actually asked a question...

Comment: @Dave The question is hidden in the first sentence: "Is this bad practice"

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to pass it an instance of B, but that doesn't eliminate the need for up casting without storing it in D.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET ah yes thanks. i didnt spot it as there wasn't a question mark

Comment: @M312V make C generic with a constraint that it's generic type parameter must of type `A<double>` and the it's `A<double>` property can be of type T, the generic parameter

Comment: You're not [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting). You're upcasting, which is perfectly OK. You can always take a more refined type and store it in a more generally typed variable without issue.

Comment: It's bad practice if you can guarantee that the cast is correct (because you have that knowledge from some additional information). But there is no guarantee here, so it's not bad, it's *wrong.*

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I made a mistake and edited the code, so there is a guarantee here. Although it's still bad practice.

Comment: IMO, the bad practice here is a field that isn’t private

Comment: @DaveM So if I made the field private and store the same instance in D, would that be a better practice or is that also wrong?

Comment: Encapsulate it with a property or method

Comment: @DaveM I decided to completely get rid of the field and encapsulate everything in Properties.

Comment: After the edit there is no reason to not make the `_a` a `B` right away; if you can give the guarantee at compile time you can enforce it by strict typing. If you cannot enforce it though you need to distinguish the types at run time, either through reflection or through some explicit data. Typical use cases are collections of generic things which can *almost all* be handled generically, except for this pesky little class which needs extra care and feeding. And that is correctly frowned upon: In a perfect world one would call virtual functions in the respective object which do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is bad practice; like *all* downcasting (sometimes necessary to be sure; but that doesn't make it good).

The following code will generate a runtime exception:

```
A<double> myA = new A<double>("Test", 1.0d);
D test = new D(myA);
var boom = test.Expression; //InvalidCastException
```

Whereas with a different structure that wouldn't even compile. For example, modifying `D` to take a `B` instead of an `A<double>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, make the C class generic

```
public class C<T> where T : A<double>
{
    public C(T thing)
    {
        _thing = thing;
    }
    protected T _thing;
}
```

Then D can be an instance of C with a generic argument of B

```
public D : C<B>
{
    Public string Expression { get {return _thing.Expression;}}
}
```

I'm on my phone so please forgive.sny formatting or typo issues

Comment: This makes it all look a bit nicer imo but with your edit to your code, I'd say it's fine with the cast and your ctor ensures that the cast with succeed